# Vuex Error Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers when commit a mutation into an action using settimout

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am using vuex in strict mode: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html

I have a state that I wanna change through a mutation as is described in de documentation. I fire this mutation into a settimeout, so it is an asynchronous mutation so I create an action as follow:

```js
menuOnResize ({ commit }) {
    if (!state.menuIsOpen) {
      window.addEventListener('resize', resizeThrottler, false)
    }
    var resizeTimeout
    function resizeThrottler () {
      if (!resizeTimeout) {
        resizeTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
          resizeTimeout = null
          commit('menuIsOpenOnResize')
        }, 500)
      }
    }
  }
```

But when the action is executed the console give me the next error:

[image]

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, I mean, I thinks I'm doing the thing in the right way, Mutating the state through a mutation an using a action because it is an asynchronous task.

*Versions of vue and vuex:
vue: 2.5.17,
vuex: 3.0.1*

Comment: Your error message doesn't seem to be matching your code, it looks like you're passing the state to a chart library and it's changing things there.

Comment: The strange thing happen here is that this error only appear when my code is executed that have no relation at all with the library, which by the way is vue-chart.js. If a commented the code that call the function menuOnResize error disappears

Comment: it's hard to speculate why you're getting this error only looking at this specific mutation. however it could be that by using "var" in defining resizeTimeout, vue treats it as a state variable. either limit its score using "let" or define it as a state variable and thus use mutations to change its value.

Comment: It is no the problem @mmbrian I reduced the code to only left the function resizeThrottler () { commit('menuIsOpenOnResize') } and the problem is still there. I will open an issue in the vue-charts github

Comment: I have opened an issue on the vue-chartjs github: https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/445

Comment: The problem must occur outside of the given code. As you can see in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EOEzgZ) the code itself works as intended